# Issue with method when called. Program is to create a buffered image for editing

Tags: methods, io, bufferedimage

I am very new to programming as you can probably tell from my code! I am creating a program to edit uploaded pictures by creating a buffered image which is then to be modified but I am having issues. My code is

```
private Scanner sc;
    private String inputPath = null;
    
    public String getInputPath() throws Exception { 
    System.out.println("Please enter the path to the picture you wish to edit.");
    sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    inputPath = sc.next();
    getFile(inputPath);
    return inputPath;
    }
    
    private File getFile(String inputPath) throws Exception{
          File f = new File(inputPath);
          while (true) {
          if (f.exists()){ 
            bufferedImage(); //line 27
            }else{
            throw new Exception("Invalid file name!");
          }
         }
    }
    
    public void bufferedImage() throws Exception {
        File f = getFile(inputPath); //line 35
        BufferedImage bi = ImageIO.read(f);
        System.out.println(bi);
        return;
        }
```

My error message is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError:
    at ie.gmit.dip.ImageWriter.getFile(ImageWriter.java:27)
    at ie.gmit.dip.ImageWriter.bufferedImage(ImageWriter.java:35)
```

I have marked the lines in my code above. Any help on this would be massively appreciated!

Comment: First of all, you should try to explain your problem better! "I'm having issues" isn't very informative. WHAT issues? What happened when you ran the program? What did you expect to happen? Second, you should include the top of the stack trace (In understand it is very long in your case). I believe it was a `StackOverflowException`.  Finally, for this specific problem, have a closer look at the lines 27 and 35. Try to follow the execution path. What happens when your methods invokes each other in turn?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response! What I am hoping is that when I run the program and select the picture to edit, that it will print out the buffered image to me to confirm that it has run correctly. When I run the program, it allows me to enter the name of the picture and comes back with "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError" and the above errors. 

Am I right in saying that I have created an infinte loop on the program?

Comment: Exactly! By having two methods that unconditionally invokes each other, you have created an endless loop (well, eventually you run out of stack space).

Comment: Many thanks Harald, I got it working fine now! Cheers